# Tilemill: set max extent for export

Tags: tilemill, extents, mapbox, cartocss

Is it possible to set map extent to be displayed on mapbox ?
If so could you please send me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please clarify your question: Do you want to want the actual bounding box coordinates displayed on your map when hosting with MapBox? Or are you asking how to set the extent of the area being exported from TileMill?

For the first you could create a legend in tooltips and just manually enter the coordinates. Copy and paste them from settings.

For the latter see #6 "Select the map 'Bounds'" in **6. Exporting a Map** in the TileMill crash course tutorial: http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/

Comment: Hi Chris exactly , the exporting map in crash course was my search. Indeed the question was a bit confuse. Thanks for the help . Jorge Vidinha